# Save Camera Image to App Package Folder

Tags: android, android-file, android-camera-intent, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider

I am trying to store the camera image under my app's package name directly. I have read other similar questions and followed this tutorial  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) exactly.

My Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;
private Button btnCamera, btnGallery;
private File file;
private Uri uri;

private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
int width, height;

public static final int CAM_CODE = 101;
public static final int GALL_CODE = 108;

public static String mCurrentPhotoPath;
public static final String Package_Name = "com.joey.example.camerasqlite";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchCamera();
        }
    });

    btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pickGallery();
        }
    });

}

public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fileName =  timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    //File storageDir = getFilesDir();
    File image = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".png", storageDir);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;

}

private void launchCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (photoFile != null){
            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, Package_Name, photoFile);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private void pickGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALL_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAM_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    if (requestCode == GALL_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }

}
```

}

App crashes at runtime with this message in logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.joey.example.camerasqlite/files/20171020_115905_1523486524.png
                                                   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
                                                   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
                                                   at com.joey.example.camerasqlite.MainActivity.launchCamera(MainActivity.java:88)
                                                   at com.joey.example.camerasqlite.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                   at com.joey.example.camerasqlite.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5690)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22693)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6269)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Here is my Manifest with the file provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.joey.example.camerasqlite"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Have added XML file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.joey.example.camerasqlite/files/Pictures"/>
    <!--<files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.joey.example.camerasqlite/files/Pictures"/>-->
</paths>
```

I need some help resolving this. Thanks

Comment: upload the code of your file_paths.xml file too.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding Package_Name? Arent you aware of function getPackageName()?

Comment: And further you do not need that variable or that function. You can just use getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: We use getFilesDir() instead of getExternalFilesDir() for internal storages. To save in external storage you need permission for that. but getFilesDir() does not need permission. Try changing it to that and see if it works and tell me if you need permissions or what?

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Your folder name"+"file name.jpg"

Comment: @SafanMomin, I have added the xml file. Have a look

Comment: @Xenolion, I have tried with both still app crashes. What does the exception mean?

Comment: Does it crash in all devices or just Android 6 and more?

Comment: Haven't tested on other devices, just Nougat

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.joey.example.camerasqlite/files/Pictures"/>
    <!--<files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.joey.example.camerasqlite/files/Pictures"/>-->
</paths>
```

with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="."/>
    <!--<files-path name="my_images" path="."/>-->
</paths>
```